# How to access variables defined in struct using 'Truffle'?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp, truffle, testrpc

This is the sample contract given :-

```
 contract User {

             string public userName;
             mapping(address => Service) public services;

             struct Service {
                   bool active;
                   uint lastUpdate;
                   uint256 debt;
            }

            function User(string _name) {
                   userName=_name;
            }

          function registerToProvider(address _providerAddress) {
               services[_providerAddress]=Service({
                        active:true,
                        lastUpdate:now,
                        debt:0
               });

          }

          function setDebt(uint256 _debt) {
                   if(services[msg.sender].active){
                         services[msg.sender].lastUpdate=now;
                         services[msg.sender].debt=_debt;
                   }
                  else {
                        throw;
                  }

         }
         function payToProvider(address _providerAddress) {

              if(!_providerAddress.send(services[_providerAddress].debt)){
                     throw;
              }

       }
       function unsubscribe(address _providerAddress){
            if(services[_providerAddress].debt== 0){
                    services[_providerAddress].active=false;
           }else {
                     throw;
           }

       }

   }
```

I have to access the variables defined in struct using truffle.
I have deployed this contract using this command

```
     var user=User.deployed()
```

I have tried to access the struct values using this command.

```
       user.Service[active].call().then(console.log)
```

But it returns error.How can i check the values in Service structure.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare a Service first in your contract:

```
Service public InstanceOfService;
```

then you can use it.